# Semantic link between πόνος and πονηρός?

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek

[Πόνος](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CF%8C%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) means toil or suffering, while [πονηρός](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%B7%CF%81%CF%8C%CF%82), derived from it, can mean either that someone toils under oppression or else is knavish, base, or evil. What is the semantic link between toil/suffering and evil? If I had to guess, I could come up with two guesses:

(1) Noblemen are ἀγαθός because that's the natural order of things, and for similar reasons, people who do hard manual labor are knavish, base, or evil for the same reason. OK, the bronze age is before any notion of the nobility of labor, but they certainly had the concept of a reliable servant, or of a character like the swineherd Eumaeus who virtuously cares for the disguised Odysseus, thinking him to be a ξένος.

(2) Maybe evil people cause suffering for the rest of us good people. But this also seems weak, since there is nothing inherently evil (in the ancient world) about causing others to toil or labor. Is the idea that πόνος specifically implies that the toil or labor is unjust, and therefore anyone who imposes πόνος on us must be bad? I suppose then we would have to have had an expansion of the word's meaning, from evil-because-they-inflict-unjust-toil to evil in general.

Comment: Nietzsche has a lot to say about the origins of "good/evil" terms in Greek in the *Genealogy of Morality*, and he definitely makes the πόνος/πονηρός connection in I.10. (He accepts a theory quite similar to your first option.) He's an excellent (albeit dated) classicist, though his overall philosophical point is (imo) more problematic.

Comment: Indeed, Beekes appears to concur with your (1): toilsome, useless, bad, evil. A bridge word is δουλοπόνηρος = bad like a slave. Has undertones of "villain".

Answer (score 2):

The link is not directly between *suffering* and *evil* but rather through a shared common root - "*twisted*" and both *suffering* and *evil*.

> According to Beekes, from Proto-Indo-European
> *(s)penh₁- (“to weave, to twist”). [From your link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CF%8C%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek)

And so the deviation from the righteous is bad, evil and bending under the (too heavy) load is suffering.

Parallel compare English *wicked/witch* and German [*wickeln*](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/Wickeln) (twist, bend)

It seems that from the same root (through Latin) comes current Spanish [*pendejo*](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2019/08/27/mexico/1566866267_742369.html) weak, evil, stupid - twisted and thin like a pubic hair. The linked article (in Spanish) describes the logic behind this.

In Slavic languages there exists a root *nur* "bend" as when preparing to dive and the word *[понурый ponury](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9#:%7E:text=%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%5B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%5D%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2.%20%2Anur-%20%22%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%22%2C,%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80.%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%CC%81%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80.%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%CC%81%D1%80%D1%8B%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%81%D0%BA.%20ponur%C3%BD%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA.%20%D1%80%D0%BEnur%D1%83.)* "bent down" as if exhausted.

Also compare the root [στενός](https://lsj.gr/wiki/%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%8C%CF%82) having two meanings:*straits/narrow* and *to groan* [στόνος](https://lsj.gr/wiki/%CF%83%CF%84%CF%8C%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82) and also in parallel *cтена* - wall and *cтон* - *a groan* in Russian.

As antonym to *to be contained between walls* is the Greek word  *free* [ἐλεύθερος](https://lsj.gr/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%8D%CE%B8%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%82) derived from *to be able to go wherever one wants* - ἐλεύσομαι.

Comment: This seems unlikely to me because (even assuming the *(s)penh₁- etymology, which the dictionaries are doubtful about) none of the Greek words from this root has anything to do with weaving or twisting, and πονηρός is clearly a Greek-internal derivative from πόνος. The earliest sense seems to be "oppressed by toils", from which it's pretty easy to get to "base, knavish" given Greek social ideology.

Comment: στενός 'narrow' and στένω 'to groan' are almost certainly unrelated to each other, and Russian стена and стон definitely are; the latter is cognate to Greek στένω, but the former is a different root altogether, related to στία 'pebble'. ἐλεύθερος isn't from ἐλεύσομαι either, though they did come from the same PIE root meaning 'to come out' (with a complicated semantic history).

Comment: @Cairnarvon, not sure what you base your statements on. Maybe you could add links to your sources? I’m using LSJ and more specifically e.g. French „Bailly abrégé“ which points to the said etymology. (All linked in my answer)

Comment: *Pendejo* also is not from *(s)penh₁- but from Lat. pecten (at least thus Wiktionary).

Comment: @TKR thanks that you have found some time to read my answer and post this comment, did you also have time to read the linked article on Pendejo?

Comment: The LSJ is from 1843 and the Bailly from 1895, and neither is more than incidentally concerned with etymology. For modern and rigorous work, the first port of call is [Beekes](http://koen.readsicp.org/leiden/10_Beekes__Etymological_Dictionary_of_Greek_I_and_II.pdf).

Comment: The linked article also says that *pendejo* is from *pecten* "comb", which comes from the same PIE root *peḱ- as Greek πέκω and various other words; it's not related to πόνος.

Comment: @Cairnarvon thank you for the link, most appreciated!